# Does the "function returning function" pattern have a name in JavaScript?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript

I use this pattern quite often in JavaScript. Here is an example:

```
const comments = [
  { text: 'Hello', id: 1 },
  { text: 'World', id: 4 },
];

const byId = id => element => element.id === id;

const comment = comments.find(byId(1));
```

Sometimes, this pattern can make our code readable and modular. What is this pattern called?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are called higher-order functions.

> A higher-order function is a function that can take another function as an argument, or that returns a function as a result. - [Higher-Order Functions in JavaScript by M. David Green](https://www.sitepoint.com/higher-order-functions-javascript/)

Comment: And you end up with a closure.

Comment: JavaScript is a language in which all functions are first class. Meaning you can pass them around in variables like any other value. A closure is a function that has access to the enclosing "lexical scope" in which it was defined. Works a bit like how an objects methods have access to the objects state variables.

Comment: In this particular case he is currying 2 args down to 1.